# How to access fields in a user control from main page containing that control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a main page and I have a user control on this page.
User control has some text fields.

How can I access those fields from my main page?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make the fields available as public properties of your user control. Something like

```
public class MyControl
{
    public Label LabelX { get { return m_LabelX; } }
    public Label LabelY { get { return m_LabelY; } }
}
```

where m_LabelX and 
in your main page then access the label like this

```
var userControlLabel = ((MyControl)m_UserControl).LabelX;
```